# if elsif else statement parsing

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

i've been working on a compiler for an imperative language using lex and yacc, and today i finished the grammar, the thing is that i've been reading on the web that every grammar is expected to have a few shift/reduce conflicts, specially if it has if/else statements, that's often known as dangling if-else, and mine does have if/elsif/else statements yet it doesn't throw any conflict when compiled, the question is

¿does that means this grammar has flaws just because it doesn't throw any shift/reduce conflicts? i dont have much experience doing this but i can't find any problem with it

In case you want some more information the productions for the if/elsif/else statements in this grammar are something like this:

```
statement -> ... 
------------| initial_conditional_stmt

initial_conditional_stmt: conditional_stmt
-----------------------| conditional_stmt 'else' block


conditional_stmt -> 'if' '(' expression ')' block
------------------| conditional_stmt elsif  '(' expression ')' block
```

block is just a list of statements inside brackets {}

Comment: Check out this IF-ELSE Parser using Flex and Bison http://c-madeeasy.blogspot.in/2012/05/if-else-statement-is-commonly-used-in.html

Answer (score 3):

No shift/reduce conflicts means you did a really good job of your language design and it's never ambiguous.

Well done, give yourself a pat on the back, relax, go grab a beer from the fridge.

Comment: that's indeed good to read, now i can peacefully begin to work on the AST, thanks!

Comment: This is a very incomplete answer. The answer by Dervall contains more useful reasoning about why there is no conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are not getting the dangling else here is because you're using a block instead of the normal statement.

For your grammar you cannot do

```
if (cond)
    if (cond) {
        [stuff]
    }
    else
    {
    }
```

You would have to do this

```
if (cond) 
{
    if (cond) {
        [stuff]
    }
    else
    {
    }   
}
```

Every nested if statement must be inside matching { }. This in your case eliminates the dangling else at the expense of a bit stranger syntax. Compared to a "normal" grammar "block" would be "statement" which could also be another if statement, thus causing the classical shift/reduce conflict.

Comment: From the beginning i was taught that writing conditional statements like in the first example is a bad practice so i really wasn't thinking in that particular case, but i think that's a good thing, forcing the programmer to enclose all the 'stuff' inside a block, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Do you mean ‘stranger’? It seems to me that Alb3rt’s syntax is stronger, but then I come from an Ada background where the equivalent of the {} is syntactically necessary; and I would always put the {} in if writing in C or similar.

Comment: I mean strange in the context of what is normal to a curly-bracers developer who would expect to be able to omit bracers for one liners. There's nothing wrong with either grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You may better to use these code as following:

```
%nonassoc XIF
%nonassoc ELSE

   stmt: IF expr stmt %prec XIF
       | IF expr stmt ELSE stmt
```

That is a way to change precedence conflict between if and else.

Hope it helps.